# LINQ group by datetime and sum

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, datetime, group-by

I have a List of orders purchased on specific date. I need to group them all into one date ( purchases made on same day) and then sum them.. I made a class which looks like this:

```
 public class StoreAnalyticOrders
    {
        public DateTime OrderDate { get; set; }
        public float AmountPaid { get; set; }

    }
```

And then the I fill the list which is called "GraphList" with results...

The LINQ that I tried to perform what I just described up there is:

```
  var result = GraphList
      .GroupBy(l => l.OrderDate)
      .Select(cl => new StoreAnalyticOrders
      {
          AmountPaid = cl.Sum(c => c.AmountPaid),
      }).ToList();
```

But for some reason the dates are in bad format (they are lost) and they show up like this:

```
1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM
```

and this is the previous format of the Order date property:

```
11/21/2016 6:05:32 AM
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Edit: @Ivan Stoev is this what you ment:

```
  var result = GraphList
                    .GroupBy(l => l.OrderDate.Date)
                     .Select(cl => new StoreAnalyticOrders
                     {
                         OrderDate = cl.Key,
                         AmountPaid = cl.Sum(c => c.AmountPaid)
                     }).ToList();
```

Comment: first, you should not group by `DateTime` straight away. you need to group by `l.OrderDate.Date` so it will trim hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds parts. therefore you have all purchases in one day grouped.

Comment: You forgot to read the date, e.g. `OrderDate = cl.Key, AmountPaid = ...`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary I did that now... Ivan I edited my question with your suggesiton... Is that it ?

Comment: yes. to me it seems it will be working, try it and see if it works. probably we should've given answer instead of comment.

Comment: Yes, it should work now.

Comment: Works like a charm :) Thanks guys !

Answer (score 1):

You can not use make changes to datetime in a linq to entities query, and you should use `DbFunctions`:

```
GraphList.GroupBy(gl => DbFunctions.TruncateTime((DateTime)gl.Datetime)).
Select(gl=> new{
    Date = DbFunctions.TruncateTime((DateTime)gl.FirstOrDefault().Datetime),
    TotalAmountPaid = gl.Sum(x=> x.AmountPaid)
}).ToList();
```